# create database tables in mysql using data from variable

Tags: php, mysql

How does one use the data from a variable to create a table with the same name?

If there is a variable called $user_data and we accessed the ['username'] value how can this be used to create a database table with the same value, so that each user can have their own table in the database, and it is named the same as their username in the database.

Is this a correct way to link tables or what is the best way to layout database data. And how are the tables and databases connected via shared data?

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE {$user_data['username']}(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query a table creation.

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "bill", "3pD]gks*dg");
mysql_select_db("user_db");
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE ".$user_data['username']."(some_text varchar(15), some_int int)");
```

Within the parenthesis of the query, you should place your desired table structure.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a really bad idea.** There is actually whole chapter "Metadata Tribbles" on this subject in [SQL Antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) book (btw, my recommendation, get it).

First of all, in the case of users, this will open you application for additional injection threats. Both simple one and and second order sql injections (read bout [here](http://www.esecforte.com/blog/second-order-sql-injection/) and [here](http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/tutorial/SQLInjection/html/lesson1/les01_tm_attacks2.htm)). And this will reduce you ability to index data.

Instead you should keep all user details in one (or two, if it a heavy use site) table, and utilize foreign key to link users to other content which then have made.

Comment: Hi. Thanks, I was thinking about the tables being guessable. What is the best way to do this. I would like each user to have their own data of different attributes. Or is it better to dump all the data into one like you said? Slower lookup times though I guess. Is there a way to set and reset database table names on the fly?